# PHP only can not hide error display for memory exhausted fatal error

Tags: php, error-handling

I found that only `memory exhausted` fatal error can not close display in PHP while other fatal errors can.

php.ini:

```
error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED & ~E_STRICT & E_COMPILE_ERROR
display_errors = Off
```

Or by PHP runtime:

```
error_reporting(0);
ini_set('display_errors', 0);
```

Above settings could hide any PHP fatal errors but only memory exhausted not.

```
Fatal error: Allowed memory size of {134217728} bytes exhausted (tried to allocate {83} bytes) in {/locate/file.php} on line 237
```

Why is memory exhausted fatal error different from other fatal errors that can be hidden by setting? Could PHP turn off the display for memory exhausted fatal error?

Thanks.

> PHP version: 5.6 & 7.0

Comment: why you want to hide it? fatal error stops the program execution. so instead of hiding it, start making your code clear and faster.

Comment: I'm investigating the principle and this is a clear problem (error_reporting exception) of PHP.